# How do I use the react-i18next <Trans> named tags?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to implement the Trans tag format described [here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#alternative-usage-v-11-6-0). However, whenever I try to copy the example, almost verbatim, the result is that the tag names appear on the page and the inner content does not.

Here is a link to [my sample project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-example-forked-2hqc4?file=/src/en.js).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the fact that `Trans` component accepts an **object** as `components` prop.

In your example you've passed a **string**.

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>{t("Welcome to React")}</h2>
          <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("de")}>de</button>
          <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("en")}>en</button>
        </div>
        <Trans
          i18nKey="userMessagesUnread"
          values={{ name: "Greg", count: "30" }}
          components={{ bold: <strong />, italic: <i /> }}
          // --------^
        ></Trans>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-example-forked-8bvc2?file=/src/app.js:140-772)

Comment: Also note that in @vball example the older version of 18next is used that does not support that

Comment: It does supports a component prop that accepts an array. Check the docs